# Selenium Installation to be redirected from anaconda to pycharm

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, anaconda

So I did

```
pip install selenium
```

in the pycharm terminal so I thought I was good to go but when I did

```
from Selenium import webdriver
```

it gave me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/askma/PycharmProjects/LinkedIn_Connection_Automation/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Selenium'
```

So I decided to check out what went wrong and found out that selenium was installed in the anaconda3 IDE

```
pip3 install selenium
Requirement already satisfied: selenium in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.141.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in c:\users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from selenium) (1.25.10)
```

How would I be able to get selenium in Pycharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly uninstall the selenium that got installed in anaconda3 IDE
[click here](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1CAZVTZ_enIN946IN946&q=How%20do%20I%20uninstall%20selenium%3F&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj2hoKw187wAhXRV30KHWkXBV0Qzmd6BAgJEAU&biw=1536&bih=746&dpr=1.25) and then perform the following steps to reinstall the selenium into Pycharm.

1. pip install selenium.
2. Go to Pycharm -> Perform (Cntrl + Alt + S) -> Select Project Interpreter -> Click on (+) icon -> Search for Selenium -> Select and Install Package -> Apply -> Ok.